# symfony composer update "don't install symfony/symfony"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I’m getting a flood of messages when I run ‘composer.phar update’
on my Centos 6.4 / `PHP 5.5.36` server
starting with:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of 
packages.

  Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.8
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.7
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.6
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.5
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.3
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1
- phpunit/phpunit 4.0.0 requires symfony/yaml ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.
```

http://pastebin.centos.org/119091/

`composer.json` is: 
http://pastebin.centos.org/119096/

Comment: Is Symfony3.0.* a requirement for you or would you consider using the current version of 3.3.*?

Comment: What's your composer.json?

Comment: He's linked it on the last line of his question.

Comment: The reason I ask about Symfony versions, is due to the fact 3.0 is not longer supported neither is 3.2. Updating your versions to 3.3 now and very soon to 3.4 will at least then mean you're on the 3.4 LTS version which will hopefully not break like this. Looking at your composer.json I notice except for the Symfony version most other bundles are set to the same versions as my current 3.3 project. I'm guessing one of these has had a breaking change which would be fixed by upping your Symfony version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint:

```
- phpunit/phpunit 4.0.0 requires symfony/yaml ~2.0
```

You're using Symfony in version `3.0.*`, which requires `symfony/yaml` package in the same version.

In the same time you're using PHPUnit in version `4.0.*` which requires `symfony/yaml`, but in version  `~2.0` (which means >=2.0.0 and <3.0.0).

So you have a conflict here.

I would suggest to update PHPUnit package to 4.8 version, which requires `symfony/yaml` in version `~2.1|~3.0`, which is compatible with Symfony 3.

Answer (score 0):

Update the composer it will resolve the issue

```
composer global update
```